# Why doesn't my WCF JSONP service not return JSONP over HTTPS

Tags: ajax, wcf, azure, jsonp

I have a WCF service that uses JSONP (which is hosted in Azure).  It works perfectly fine over HTTP, i.e., if it receives JSON only it returns JSON only, and if it receives JSONP it returns JSONP.  However as soon as I change over to HTTPS (providing only the HTTPS endpoint in Azure) it returns JSON only regardless of whether the call is JSON or JSONP.  My configuration for HTTP is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">          
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And in the services Global.asax file I have:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("DirectTvService", new WebScriptServiceHostFactory(), typeof(DirectTVService.DirectTvService)));
    }       
}
```

I want to change from HTTP to HTTPS, so I add

```
<security mode="Transport">
</security>
```

to the standardEndpoint tag, thus:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And I change my IIS7 binding from HTTP to HTTPS.  With this configuration the service works as expected for JSON, but only return JSON for JSONP requests (the response is not wrapped in the callback function.

An example of my client request (in CoffeeScript) is:

```
$.ajax
url: callUrl
dataType: 'jsonp'
data: 
    username: $('#txtUsername').val()
    password: $('#txtPassword').val()
success: (data) =>
    $.unblockUI()
    Application.processLoginData data
    false
error: (d, msg, status) ->
    $.unblockUI()
    alert "There was a problem contacting the database. " + status
    false
```

And my service method is decorated with:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public LoginResponse LoginUser(String username, String password)
```

Any ideas?

Kurt

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, a working solution was to have both HTTP and HTTPS endpoints in the Azure configuration, but only provide a single endpoint in my WCF configuration.  I used the following serviceModel configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and everything worked fine.  As soon as I delete the HTTP endpoint in the Azure configuration, JSONP stops working (just returns JSON), and if I add

```
<security mode="Transport">
</security>
```

to the standardEndPoint (as I would expect to have to do for HTTPS) it also stops working...